# Postgresql get the distinct count when using limit and offset

Tags: postgresql

I'm just wondering if there is an easy way to get a distinct count when selecting a joined multiple rows query and using limit and offset as pagination in postgresql.

For example, I have 3 tables, student, teacher, and relational table between the student and teacher.

student table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Student1 |
| 2 | Student2 |
| 3 | Student3 |
| 4 | Student4 |
| 5 | Student5 |
| 6 | Student6 |
| 7 | Student7 |
| 8 | Student8 |
| 9 | Student9 |

... and so on up to Student100

teacher table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Teacher1 |
| 2 | Teacher2 |
| 3 | Teacher3 |

student_teacher table:

| id | studentId | teacherId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |

... and so on until all 100 students are with teacher1, teacher2, and teacher3

Here is my current sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(student.*), COUNT(*) OVER() AS "total_count" from student
JOIN student_teacher on student_teacher.studentId = student.id
JOIN teacher on student_teacher.teacherId = teacher.id
WHERE teacher.id = 2
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

the "total_count" would be 300, but I want it to be 100 instead because there are only 100 distinct student (I can see that there are only 100 rows).

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one (or more) of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`  and `distinct (t.*), x` is the same as `distinct t.*, x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function after you filter the table `student_teacher` for `teacherId = 2` and then join to `students`.

```
SELECT s.*, st.total_count  
FROM student s
JOIN (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_count 
  FROM student_teacher 
  WHERE teacherId = 2
) st ON st.studentId = s.id
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

There is no need to join `teachers`.

Comment: ah, yes, I was simplifying the query, the original query has more than just one relationship table, so I needed the join to teacher table.. but I am currently thinking how to incorporate the above query to my reusable function..

Comment: actually, when I run the inner JOIN (select *, count( * ) over() as total_count), I still get the 300 as total count, so maybe this will not work..

Comment: @GlenK `WHERE teacherId = 2` is applied first and then `COUNT(*) OVER()` calculates the number of students. So, if you get 300 then there are 300 students for `teacherId = 2`. Is there a case that you have duplicate students for a teacher?

Comment: I will have a look at it again tomorrow.. as I said, I am simplifying the query, so maybe there is something wrong with the my query.. will let you know how it goes.. thanks

Comment: I found the issue.. in the actual query, I used a LEFT JOIN to another table, and in the where clause I also have "IS NOT NULL".. maybe I should fix the query or post another question because your answer is correct given the simple query..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the answer that you are looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(student.*),(select count(DISTINCT(student_id)) from student_teacher) as total_count  from student
JOIN student_teacher on student_teacher.studentId = student.id
JOIN teacher on student_teacher.teacherId = teacher.id
WHERE teacher.id = 2
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: the (select count(*) from student) as total_count will give the number of student = 100, even if I delete one of the student relationship with the teacher2

Comment: @GlenK I edited my answer. Now count is on the "student_teacher" table.